# Paste Special with powershell and excel

Tags: excel, powershell, powershell-2.0

Using Powershell 2.0 I am trying to copy the results of a formula in one worksheet to another. In order to do this I need to use paste special (otherwise I get #value error). 
However, the following code is not working. The first block is just a regular paste that works fine, but the second block has the paste special and it doesn't work. The error I get is below.

The question does anyone know what this error means or what the best way to do a paste special using Powershell and Excel is?

Works:

```
$worksheet.activate()
$sessionidcopyrange = $worksheet.Range("J1").EntireColumn
$sessionidcopyrange.copy()
$worksheet2.activate()
$sessionidpasterange =$worksheet2.Range("A1")
$worksheet2.paste($sessionidpasterange, $false)
```

Doesn't work:

```
$worksheet.activate()
$codecopyrange = $worksheet.Range("Q1").EntireColumn
$codecopyrange.copy()
$worksheet2.activate()
$codepasterange = $worksheet2.Range("B1")
$worksheet2.pastespecial(-4163, $false)

Exception calling "PasteSpecial" with "2" argument(s): "PasteSpecial method of 
Worksheet class failed"
At line:33 char:25
+ $worksheet2.pastespecial <<<< (-4163, $false)
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation
```

Comment: My thought is that you are not yet, elsewhere in your code using either the Office / excel interop assemblies or Excel.application that you should look at those.

Comment: I have this: `$excel = New-Object -comobject excel.application` at the top of my code

Comment: wouldn't it be `$codepasterange.pastespecial(-4163, $false)`

Answer (score 3):

Example:

```
$Dest = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()
$Dest.ActiveSheet.Range("B:C").copy()
$Dest.ActiveSheet.Range("D1").Select()
$Dest.ActiveSheet.Range("D1").PasteSpecial(-4163)
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste special with PowerShell and Excel:

The second value is of type `XlPasteSpecialOperation`.

`$worksheet2.pastespecial(-4163, $false)`
should be
`$worksheet2.pastespecial(-4163, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone)`